# How to avoid duplicate printing of random choiced names from list ( Python)

Tags: python-2.7, duplicate-data

This program prints duplicate names generated from list please help me get rid of it I added a operator fr it but it's not working

```
#Subscriber Selector
import random
print "Welcome to Subscriber Picker"
sub_list = ["Ali Abbas","Ansar Abbasi","Hasan Abidi","Saadia Afzaal","Iqbal       Ahmad","Iftikhar Ahmad","Khaled Ahmed","Ahmed Tamim","Maulana Mahboob Alam","Malik Barkat Ali"]

def add_list():
    input_1 = int(raw_input("How many new users do you want to add? "))
for z in range (0,input_1):
    sub_list.append(raw_input ("Enter Name" +" "+ str(z+1) + ":"))
return
add_list()

def generator():
 input_2=int(raw_input("How many subscribers to generate? "))
 print "-----"
 index=0
 temp_list = []
 ran_name = random.randint(0, len(sub_list)-1)
 temp_list.append(sub_list[ran_name])
 while len(temp_list) < input_2:
      ran_name=random.randint(0,len(sub_list)-1)
      temp_list.append(sub_list[ran_name])
      if(temp_list[index] == temp_list[index+1]):
          temp_list.pop(index)       
      else:
          index = index + 1
 for x in temp_list:
      print x        
 print"-----"
 return
```

generator()

Comment: @DSM In fact this is literally the same code except that the indentation is now wrong.

Comment: can anybody answer???

Comment: @senshin: except that the now-deleted question actually had more information in a comment than this one, and so was better. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
temp_list = random.sample( sub_list, input_2 )
```

Comment: I cant use other libraries then mentioned in above?

Comment: `while len(temp_list) < input_2:
      ran_name=random.randint(0,len(sub_list)-1)
      temp_list.append(sub_list[ran_name])
      if(temp_list[index] == temp_list[index+1]):
          temp_list.pop(index)       
      else:
          index = index + 1`

Comment: Have you actually tried what I proposed?  Its documented here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

Comment: The above solution appears to do exactly what you want and will not create duplicates.

Comment: Basically I want to avoid duplicate name printing in output for which I created this below operation but this doesn't work! I can't use operator and libraries other than mentioned in my programme! while len(temp_list) < input_2: ran_name=random.randint(0,len(sub_list)-1) temp_list.append(sub_list[ran_name]) if(temp_list[index] == temp_list[index+1]): temp_list.pop(index) else: index = index + 1 for x in temp_list: print x

Comment: `random` is already imported in OP, surely you can use functions from it!